# pvl8.control file in postgresql is not present

Tags: windows, postgresql, plv8

I'm trying to execute a ./run sentence, but when I try to execute it I get this error:

ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/share/extension/plv8.control": No such file or directory

Is that problem related to the version of the postgresql?

Comment: plv8 runs ok on postgresql 9.4 according to the readme here Ref https://github.com/plv8/plv8 How are you running postgresql on windows? binary or Cygwin ? Have you got plv8 installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PLV8 version is the correct version for your Postgres DB.
**if youre using PSQL 9.4, then you need the plv8 files for PostgreSQL 9.4**

I know for Postgresql 9.5 you can find them here:
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/360-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.5-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html

and for Postgres 9.4 you can find them here:
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/341-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-9.4-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html